# Find hash in Redis database by field

Tags: node.js, database, redis

I have a `redis` server running on my local machine and I'm facing an issue when getting all keys and reading their values (hashes). let's say I have 100000 accounts, is there any way I can find the one I want by "uuid" or "email" and "password" without lagging out the whole database (current case).

I have already tried getting keys using "ACCOUNT_*" and then reading all fields to find what I want, but as I said it causes a lot of lag when there's many accounts

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It really sounds like you're using the wrong tool.  Why are you not using a SQL database if you're looking for SQL-database type functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a perfect use case for [RediSearch](https://oss.redis.com/redisearch/Quick_Start/). It will automatically create and maintain secondary indices for your hashes or JSON documents and allow for SQL-like search.

```
FT.CREATE accounts ON HASH PREFIX 1 acct: SCHEMA uuid TAG SORTABLE
OK

HSET acct:1 uuid a1 key1 val11 key2 val12
(integer) 1

HSET acct:2 uuid a2 key1 val21 key2 val22
(integer) 1

HSET acct:3 uuid a3 key1 val31 key2 val32
(integer) 1

FT.SEARCH accounts "@uuid:{a1}"
1) (integer) 1
2) "acct:1"
3) 1) "uuid"
   2) "a1"
   3) "key1"
   4) "val11"
   5) "key2"
   6) "val12"
```

Comment: what if i want to find an account for other fields? like email or password, or in this case "key1" and "key2"?

Comment: Just add these fields into FT.CREATE statement as TAG or TEXT